# Looping through a CSV file for staging purposes

Tags: python, csv

Good morning guys

this time I'm not coming with a specific code question but rather with a "am I on the right track" question.

I want to write a script for staging network equipment. I'll get a cvs list with two columns: Hostname + HW Type, something like:

```
Hostname,Type
TestAP-1,AP250
TestAP-2,AP250
TestAP-3,AP250
TestSW-1,SW100
TestSW-2,SW100
TestAP-4,AP250
```

The real list will obviously be much longer.

My idea up to now is to parse arguments who calling the script for the HW Type to get a list of Hostnames. Then connect to the hardware (IP Address will always be the same default IP or via serial console), send some commands to the hardware (set hostname, syslog server ip, etc.), read the values again from the machine (with show commands) and write the result into another csv file.

something like:

```
staging.py AP250
get a list with all hostnames where the HW Type is AP250
loop
connect (ssh or serial) to the hardware
commands:
  set hostname 'hostname'
  set syslog ip (fixed ip address, the same for all devices)
  set whatever need to be set as well
the do a show on these settings and parse the value
write the value to a output csv file (create or append)
```

Am I on the right track? Right now, my script looks like the following:

```
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('Type', type=str,
                    help='REQUIRED: Please enter the Hardware Type (AP250, SW100, etc)')

args = parser.parse_args()

Manager = "manager.domain.com"
MACAddress = "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff"

with open("input.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Type'] == args.Type:

            print(row['Hostname']) # This will later on be replaced by some paramiko code
            h = (row['Hostname'])
            t = (row['Type'])

            outdict = {}
            print (outdict)

            """
            with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as o:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(o, delimiter=',', fieldnames=["Hostname", "Type", "Hivemanager", "MACAddress"])
                writer.writeheader()
                newrow = (h + "," + t + "," + Manager + "," + MACAddress)
                writer.writerow(newrow)
                #writer.writerows(['Hostname'], ['Type'], Manager)

            print (open('output.csv', 'r').read())
            """
        input("Press Enter to continue")
```

Where I'm unsure:

- is working with dictionaries the right way to do this?
- is looping through the list of hostnames and doing everything within that loop the right way?

I don't expect fully working scripts as answers. Rather than that, some tips or links where I can get some ideas would be great.

thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, is working with dictionaries the right way of doing it or not, the answer is twofold. Firstly, if you are aiming at the `csv` reader, then absolutely *yes*. This is the right way of doing it. You get your input data in a CSV format and hence there is no sensible way around the `csv.DictReader`. Secondly, the output part; this is where you would like to store the return values. You don't necessarily need a dictionary for this, a list would be easier in my opinion. You plan on using `outdict` for this, right? But this is again a matter of personal taste, a dictionary works as well, just the access to the data is a little different. The bottom line is: Yes, you are on the right track for question one.

What (sensible) alternative would there be to looping over the hostnames and performing all the actions on a *per hostname basis*? This minimizes the login actions you have to perform to the respective hosts and if you loose network connection in the middle of your script, you only have to repair one host, not all of them.

I hope this helps you.